# German national visa in two countries

Tags: visas, germany

Can I get the German National Visa application submitted in a German consulate in a country and get the passport stamped after visa approval in another German consulate/VFS in another country?

Comment: Probably not.  Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I reside in a foreign country where I have applied for the German visa with a valid job offer from Germany. And I wish to travel to my home country to collect the visa after approval - from the German embassy there. Time/appointment constraints and personal reasons.

Comment: Not likely. They probably have no way to send your information and documents from one consulate to another. And you don't live in your home country anyway.

Comment: The easiest way would be to call up both embassies or consulates and ask them.

Answer (score 2):

If I answer your question in a generic way i.e. specifying if it is possible or not then: *yes, it is possible to do that*. A number of applicants get their visas stamped in another country. Having said that the process could be troublesome and the embassy/consulate concerned would take it on a case basis.

However, it is totally at the discretion of the embassy or consulate you are dealing with and the answers you find here are mostly opinions and would be case specific. As suggested in the comments, you should call up the embassies and try to explain your situation.